# R: xml2 extracts more nodes than expected

Tags: r, web-scraping, libxml2, rvest, xml2

I do not understand why this code

```
library(rvest)
u <- "http://alistapart.com/article/daemonskin"
h <- read_html(u)
html_nodes(h, "div.main-content[itemprop='articleBody'] a") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

matches many URLs that are beyond the scope of the targeted `<div>` element.

If you look at the HTML source of the [target page](http://alistapart.com/article/daemonskin):

- There is only one `<div>` that matches my query. It starts at line 177.
- The `<div>` stops at line 396.
- Yet many of the URLs returned by `html_nodes` in the code above are extracted from nodes beyond that line, outside of that `<div>`.

**Note:** You might notice that, at line 242 of the HTML, there is a faulty `</div` element. However, fixing it does not seem to resolve the issue.

I guess that the problem has to do with how `xml2` (i.e. `libxml2`) is parsing the code.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the *main* problem is poorly-crafted, non-compliant HTML at the site that prides itself on actually being smarter than everyone else in that regard.

When you do:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

URL <- "http://alistapart.com/article/daemonskin"

read_html(URL) %>%
  html_nodes("div.main-content[itemprop='articleBody'] a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str()
##  chr [1:74] "#comments" ...
```

the underlying `libxml2` library is "fixing up" minor HTML (XML) errors and has it's own way of doing things. Such ways cause more elements to be under that particular `<div>` you're targeting due to the way the parser "fixed" the HTML.

You can see the difference with the results from a real browser, which we can simulate with selenium:

NOTE: I started phantomjs in webdriver mode outside of R

```
library(seleniumPipes)

rd <- remoteDr(browserName = "phantomjs", port = 8910)
rd %>% go(URL)
```

When you do that, it's phantomjs (webkit, really) applying it's own browser-based HTML parser fixup methods to the HTML it receives (and, it's also adding or subtracting nodes based on any javascript triggers on page load).

When you use the equivalent of `document.querySelectorAll()` to retrieve the nodes you get 34 (which is also what I got in Chrome in the Developer Tools console):

```
rd %>%
  findElements("css", "div.main-content[itemprop='articleBody'] a") %>%
  map_chr(getElementAttribute, "href") %>%
  str()
##  chr [1:34] "http://alistapart.com/article/daemonskin#comments" ...
```

NOTE that if you decide to do what I normally do and use `getPageSource()` to do all the selecting/extracting via `rvest`/`xml2` functions, you'll get a different result since it extracts the current HTML page from the virtual browser and passed it to `read_html()` which has `libxml2` applying some additional fixup to what webkit theoretically already cleaned up:

```
rd %>%
  go(URL) %>%
  getPageSource() %>%
  html_nodes("div.main-content[itemprop='articleBody'] a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str()
##  chr [1:32] "#comments" ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the `phantomjs` proof that the issue is the HTML and how `libxm2` patched it up. It's a strange issue, however, and I did not find how to actually patch the code (what to add to/remove from it) to resolve the issue. Did you find the tag responsible for the issue?

Comment: Also, thanks for editing the question to improve the tagging.

Comment: selenium or phantom rly aren't too bad to get going on a system. i'll try to carve out some time to compare the structural changes of the doc.

Comment: I've just run phantomjs + your code, works like a charm, thanks again for all the pointers. Also, I've opened an issue on GitHub about this, mentioning you and the webmasters who should fix the errors in the HTML code.

Comment: Related to your answer, I just stumbled upon this: https://github.com/rstudio/webdriver -- looks cool!